Include aditional data (jsonb) to PostGIS MVTgeom from query
I am trying to understand how I would add additional data to a MVT tile in a PostGIS query.
Currently i use martin (https://martin.maplibre.org/) to serve tiles. Internally it does a query like this:
SELECT
    ST_AsMVT(tile, 'cityJsons', 4096, 'geom', 'id')
FROM (
    SELECT
        ST_AsMVTGeom(
            ST_Transform(ST_CurveToLine("ground_geometry"), 3857),
            ST_TileEnvelope(17, 69881, 43588),
            4096, 64, true
        ) AS geom,
        "id", "attributes", "cj_metadata_id", "geometry", "id", "object_id", "type"
    FROM
        "cjdb"."city_object"
    WHERE
        "ground_geometry" && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(17, 69881, 43588, margin => 0.015625), 3857)
    LIMIT 100000
) AS tile;


Currently it returns the MVT tile with some property data like this  ( the tile was converted using : tippecanoe-decode tile.mvt 17 69881 43588 )
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1042223,
      "properties": {
        "roofType": "1000",
        "creationDate": "2018-01-12T00:00:00+01:00",
        "measuredHeight": 21.703,
        "DatenquelleLage": "1000",
        "DatenquelleDachhoehe": "1000",
        "Grundrissaktualitaet": "2017-04-04",
        "DatenquelleBodenhoehe": "1200",
        "cj_metadata_id": 1290,
        "id": 1042223,
        "object_id": "DEST_GUID_1508849109837_6998",
        "type": "BuildingPart"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
.....
        ]
      }

in the query it shows that it also exports these columns:
"id", "attributes", "cj_metadata_id", "geometry", "id", "object_id", "type"
BUT: geometry and attributes (both jsonb columns) are  nowhere to be seen in the output. Looking at the db it shows that it is a jsonb comlumn:

So - why is the row geometry (which would be the most importand for me...) not included,
and how would I include it in the output of the mvt tile?

The official MVT specification does not support nested objects in the feature attributes - either flatten your JSONB columns into top-level key/value pairs or convert to a string if you can work with that downstream.

thanks! My plan is to use mvt tiles to work with tiled cityJson (not geoJson) files from a certain zoom level. so my idea was to use a db function to pass the cityjson too in the tile. Is there any other concept i could go for here? i will try to make it a string and see how far i get here ;)
